# How Cardano is going to be more digital inclusive in sub Saharan Africa

Tags: wallet

what API's is Cardano RealFi  going to use and how do we also integrate local languages on the Plutus platform

Answer (score 0):

There are many different developments at the moment that could help with inclusion in Africa. While this is one of the main missions for Cardano, it doesn't mean it is going to be in the short term.

Keep in mind Cardano is not ready yet: the [full roadmap](https://roadmap.cardano.org/en/) includes 5 different stages, of which we are currently between Goguen (smart contracts) and Basho (scaling). Although some milestones from other phases, like decentralization and governance, keep happening in parallel.

I identify the following features and research as key for the development of Cardano in Africa and many other underdeveloped continents:

- Decentralized identity: https://atalaprism.io/app
- Light wallets: https://summit.cardano.org/sessions/light-wallets-the-path-to-accessibility-for-all
- Offline solutions for areas with connectivity issues: https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-can-give-crypto-a-cash-like-experience/33499

And in addition to all this, there is also room for the community to propose its own ideas and projects through [Project Catalyst](https://cardano.ideascale.com/): there is a specific challenge for Africa called "[Grow Africa, Grow Cardano](https://cardano.ideascale.com/c/campaigns/26600/about)".

Comment: Also check Cardano Catalyst https://cardano.ideascale.com for projects being worked on. There has been a lot of focus and funding towards African based projects. Feel free to propose your own projects if you see a gap or an opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The very APIs that are live today and growing from providers like BlockFrost.
2. Plutus Platform is a living project and so will not only require a capable multilingual/internationalisation team but also one that is well trained in the technical aspects, to keep up with changes across board.